# User-defined join function in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions

I have two tables T1 and T2 that resemble vertical partitions of a wider table T in a PostgreSQL database.

I would like to inexpensively join those partitions by using table scan operations on each of the tables, similar to a MERGE-JOIN-like operation that combines rows pairwise to a new row. My approach would assume that the tables can be merge-joined in their scan order, without sorting or checking any join predicates. The main goal is to avoid explicit joins using some row identifier that also needs to be replicated into all partitions, which seems to be the common pattern for vertical partitioning in PG.

The tables T1 and T2 have no indexes and are strictly read-only. Thus the optimizer will find no alternative way to access them in a different order. Parallel query is disabled to avoid parallel scan operations.

[obsolete Q1) Given these precautions, is there any guarantee whatsoever in PG that the rows are always returned in insertion order, e.g. after VACUUMing? ]

Q2) Is it possible to write a UDF that implements the MERGE-JOIN-like operations, i.e. something similar to:

```
SELECT T1.*, func('T2') FROM T1;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM func('T1', 'T2');
```

It seems to boil down to writing a user-defined join operator for PG.

Some more thoughts: My understanding is that PL/pgSQL functions accumulate the result in RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY, which might be expensive if T has many rows. Not sure if cursors have similar overhead. So I really do not know where to start looking.

**EDIT:**
I made the mistake of asking two questions. Please ignore the first one about guarantees. - I understand that there are no such guarantees, I was just curious of what exactly might cause problems in PostgreSQL, since I am not familiar with that system.

To clarify the use-case: I am planning to put the data into external read-only files, e.g. CSVs, accessible through foreign tables, where I have full control over the scan order. Think of it as some data archive.

Q: Is it possible to write a user-defined function in PostgreSQL that handles one cursor (Example 1) or two cursors (Example 2) and 'splice' rows emitted by two sequential scans on the server side?

Comment: Postgres 12 will do that automatically for you ("partition wise join") if you use the built-in declarative partitioning

Comment: "*is there any guarantee  whatsoever in PG that the rows are always returned in insertion order*" - a clear **NO** (not only for Postgres, but for all relational databases). The **only** way to guarantee a result order is to use an `ORDER BY`, there is no alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to partition-wise joins. But to my understanding this is all about horizontal partitioning, e.g. by range?

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. The order of SQL statement results is variable without an `ORDER BY`:

- Every `UPDATE` will change the physical location of a table row.
- There is no guarantee that an `INSERT` occurs at the end of a table.
- Even if there are no changes, a sequential scan will not always start at the beginning.

The only way you can sort of make it work is if you fill the data into an empty table in the correct order, never again modify the table and set `synchronous_seqscan` to `off`, but I guess that is not what you want to do.

I think your idea is a premature optimization, and you should create a foreign key and join the way Codd wanted it. Alternatively, if your main problem is the very many columns, perhaps you can lump the less important attributes together into a `jsonb` column which PostgreSQL can store out of line in a TOAST table if it gets too big.

Comment: "The only way you can sort of make it work is if you fill the data into an empty table in the correct order, never again modify the table and set synchronous_seqscan to off, but I guess that is not what you want to do." - as the question states, that is exactly what I want.  Let's say I understand the risks involved, is there a way to do it?

Comment: There is no way to "join" that tables that way inside the database. You could establish two concurrent database sessions in different threads in your application, run `SELECT * FROM ...` in both and splice the rows together in the application in the order they arrive. I think that is a frail architecture.